# Undeclared Identifier Error in C

Tags: c

I have this short C Code. But when I try to run the C program for the file below it shows the following errors

```
#define MAX 1000 - use of undeclared identifier
roundrobin(schedule, n); too long for functional call
```

Where am I going wrong?

EDITED FULL CODE FOR MAKING A ROUNDROBIN (Ref:http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/97/roundrobin)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 1000

int roundrobin(int schedule[MAX][MAX], int n);


int main(void)

{
    int schedule[MAX][MAX];
    int n, r, i, rounds;

    /* Input number of teams in the schedule. */
    printf("Enter the number of teams that you want a schedule for: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    /* If the number of teams is even, requires n-1 rounds; if odd, requires n. */

    if (n % 2)
        rounds = n;
    else
        rounds = n-1;

    roundrobin(schedule, n);

    /* Print a nice table. */
    printf("\n       team\n     \\ ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%6d", i+1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("round \\");
    for (i = 0; i < 6 * n; i++)
        printf(".");
    printf("\n");
    for (r = 0; r < rounds; r++)
    {
        printf("%6d:", r+1);
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%6d", schedule[r][i] + 1);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* Check the schedule and print whether or not it's valid. */
    if (check(schedule, n))
        printf("Schedule is valid.\n");
    else
        printf("Schedule is not valid.\n");
}

/*************************************************************************
 Compute the round-robin tournament schedule for n teams. If n is even,
 then there are n-1 rounds; if n is odd, there are n rounds and each team
 is idle in exactly one round. A team being idle is indicated by the
 schedule saying that it plays team number -1 in a round.
 *************************************************************************/
int roundrobin(int s[MAX][MAX], int n)
{
    int rounds, m, r, i;

    /* m is the lowest even number greater than or equal to n. */
    if (n % 2)
        m = n + 1;
    else
        m = n;

    /* If the number of teams is even, requires n-1 rounds; if odd, requires n. */

    if (n % 2)
        rounds = n;
    else
        rounds = n-1;

    /* Fill in the table with a nice diagonal pattern. */
    for (r = 0; r < rounds; r++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
            s[r][i] = ((rounds+r-i+1) + m) % m;
        for (i = r; i < n; i++)
            s[r][i] = ((rounds+r-i) + m) % m;
    }

    /* Now, do knight-like moves with the 0 in the first row. Every time the 0
     lands on a number, put that number in the first column. */
    r = 0;
    for (i = m-2; i > 0; i--)
    {
        r = ((r - 2) + rounds) % rounds;
        s[r][0] = s[r][i];
        s[r][i] = 0;
    }

    /* If m != n, then remove team n from all the games, and replace with -1. */
    if (m != n)
        for (i = 0; i < rounds; i++)
            s[i][i] = -1;
}

/*************************************************************************
 Looks at a schedule and determines whether it is valid.
 *************************************************************************/
int check(int s[MAX][MAX], int n)
{
    int game[MAX][MAX];
    int rounds, r, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            game[i][j] = 0;

    /* If the number of teams is even, requires n-1 rounds; if odd, requires n. */

    if (n % 2)
        rounds = n;
    else
        rounds = n-1;

    /* Count the number of times every team plays every other team. */
    for (r = 0; r < rounds; r++)
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            j = s[r][i];
            if (j > -1)
            /* A value of -1 would mean that team i is idle this round. */
            {
                /* Record that teams i and j played. */
                game[i][j] ++;
                game[j][i] ++;
                /* Note that we will double-count the games, because we record it
                 when team i plays j, as well as when j plays i. */
            }
        }

    /* Make sure that every pair played exactly once, and nobody ever played
     themselves. */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (game[i][i] != 0)
        /* If a team plays themselves, it's not a valid schedule. */
        { printf("Team %d played itself.\n", i); return 0; }
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        /* We have to check for a 2, because games are double-counted. */
            if (game[i][j] != 2)
            /* If two teams didn't play exactly one time, it's not valid. */
                return 0;
    }

    /* Make sure that each team plays at most once per round. */
    for (r = 0; r < rounds; r++)
    {
        /* We will use game[0] to count the number of times each team appears in
         a round. */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            game[0][i] = 0;
        /* Count number of times each teams appears in round r. */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            j = s[r][i];
            /* Team i played team j in round r. */
            if (j >= 0)
            /* -1 means that team i was idle this round. */
                game[0][j] ++;
        }
        /* Make sure each team appears at most once. */
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (game[0][i] > 1)
            /* Team i appeared more than once in round r. Not valid. */
                return 0;
    }

    /* Make sure that when team i plays team j, team j also plays team i. */
    for (r = 0; r < rounds; r++)
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            j = s[r][i];
            /* Team i played team j in round r. */
            if (j >= 0)
            /* -1 means that team i was idle this round. */
                if (s[r][j] != i)
                /* If team j didn't play team i, not valid. */
                    return 0;
        }

    /* Otherwise, the schedule is valid. */
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the exact error messages from your compiler? The first one you have there makes no sense. Also looks like you have a non-terminated comment. Please fix that.

Comment: This is incomplete code, and also it seems things have been copied/pasted in the wrong places (eg "void main()" in the middle of the function, comment not closed properly, etc.).

Comment: Also note that your program will likely fail at run time once you get it to compile. On a machine with 32-bit `int`s you'll be trying to put ~4MB on the stack, which is likely to cause a stack overflow.

Comment: i have edited and pasted the full code. i need to devise a roundrobin code that will work for my local school team so that we can plan it correctly. i am a novice in c language and not able to figure out where there is a mistake

Comment: Update your question to include the *exact* copy-and-pasted error messages. Your code compiles without error on my system.

Comment: @GirishBantwal I am able to build an executable from your code on Linux using gcc 4.7.3. What platform are you using?

Comment: @AndrewMedico On my gcc installation, it gets stack overflow at MAX=719 (stack size about 2MB) however you can pass a commandline option to gcc to use a bigger stack, for example I set it to 1GB stack and set MAX=15000 and it did not overflow. Is there any intrinsic reason you expected 4MB to be too much, or is it just that you're used to the gcc default?

Comment: You guys are right when i run in an online c compiler the code works just fine. But i am using xCode here on my brothers computer as a C program Compiler. I have stored the file with a extension as "main.c".When i compile the code the error log keeps saying the same thing - Use of Undeclared Identifier 'MAX'. Maybe i am not understanding something of XCODE - i opened the project as a template of c program only not of iOS or MAC OS or anyother thing..i have kept it simple even so XCODE isnt compiling it right.

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
if (check(schedule, n))
```

`check` is an undeclared identifier. Perhaps that is what your error message actually said. To fix this, you need to add this line near the start of the file:

```
int check(int s[MAX][MAX], int n);
```

You can put that just after the declaration of `roundrobin`.

Aside from that, there are no compilation errors in this code.